# Writing functional tests with WP_UnitTestCase

Tags: wordpress, unit-testing, selenium

TL;DR Anyone knows how to log in a user when running selenium tests over Wordpress with `facebook/php-webdriver`?

I am trying to test a Wordpress based application using Selenium and the `WP_UnitTestCase`.

For my app to load, I need a **logged in user**, so I created a fixture:

```
public function setUp() {

    $user_id = 1;
    $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
    if( $user ) {
        wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
        do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
    }

    $host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';

    $desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
    $desired_capabilities->setCapability( 'acceptSslCerts', false );
    $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create( $host, $desired_capabilities );
}
```

Unfortunately, the browser opened by the webdriver does not seem to share the state/cookies of the running unit test, so there will be no user logged in, even though from within the unit test itself, the user *is* logged in. At least that's what I'm seeing right now.

As seen in the [example](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/community/example.php), the webdriver can set cookies, and I assume I will have to simulate a logged in user that way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just curious, why you're mixing Selenium and the `WP_UnitTestCase` together?

Comment: @birgire Because I need the Wordpress API/functions in my functional tests. Or so I thought.